# How to identify the the words in the sentence that contribute to the particular sentiment?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, huggingface

So I am using pretrained tranformers model to perform sentimental analysis but I want to check what are the words which leads to that particular sentiment class. Can anyone please guide me on what should be my approach?
Below is the code I am using

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
MODEL = "nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, add_special_tokens=False,
                           return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**tokens)

probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs[0], dim=-1)
probs = probs.mean(dim=0)
"""in this model the range is from 1-5,
1-highly neg
2-negative
3-neutral
4-positive
5-higly pos
so here we will find the max from tensor and its index so we can map our sentiment"""
sen_dict= {1:'Highly-negative',2:'Negative',3:'Neutral',4:'Positive',5:'Highly-positive'}
sen_idx = probs.max(dim=0).indices.item() + 1 #added 1 as the range here is 0-4 and we want to map it between 1-5
sentiment = sen_dict[sen_idx]
print(sentiment)
```

Comment: What specifically are you using to perform sentiment analysis?  Please post some code that shows how you are doing it, that would help towards an answer.

Comment: Hello, I added my code in the post

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, there are 3 or 4 main approaches.

First you could repeatedly leave one token out, and see which words change the sentiment score. This is a bit rough, but can be used with your existing `SequenceClassification` model.

Second, you could get/train a model to tell you the indexes of the most contributing word/words in your sentence. I'm mentioning it for completeness as the third way is better. Though this is the chat LLM approach: "Tell me the word that contributes most to sentiment of ...".

Third, you could get/train a model to tell you about the sentiment of each token, rather than the sentiment of the whole sentence.  With HuggingFace this might be as simple as switching from `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` to [`AutoModelForTokenClassification`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoModelForTokenClassification).

You would obviously need to find a model trained to give per-token sentiment. Or collect some training data, and train it yourself. (Most training data has sentiment at the sentence level.)

The fourth way is to go old skool: before transformers and seq2seq models we had lexicons that listed the sentiment of words. And then the simplest way to find sentiment of a sentence was to add up the sentiment of each individual words.